# orthogonality - which vector in the subspace W is closest with y

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I'm having some difficulties by calculating the vector which is closest with y. We have 2 vectors and y and the question is: which vector in W = span(u1, u2) is closest with y.

where:
$$u1 = \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ -1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} u2 = \begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ -3 \\ -2 \end{bmatrix} y = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 2 \\ 6 \end{bmatrix}$$

So what I've tried first was using Gram-Schmidt algoritme which led to the following orthonormal matrix:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} \frac{3}{\sqrt{14}} \\ \frac{-1}{\sqrt{14}} \\ \frac{2}{\sqrt{14}} \end{bmatrix} ,\begin{bmatrix} \frac{2}{\sqrt{24}} \\ \frac{-2}{\sqrt{24}} \\ \frac{-4}{\sqrt{24}} \end{bmatrix}$$

These are orthonormal vectors but if I have to calculate the distance with these vectors then I have some really odd numbers. Anybody thoughts about that? Help would be appreciated! Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call the two vectors that you (correctly) got through Gram Schmidt $v_1$ and $v_2$.  The closest vector to $y$ in $W$ is given by
$$
y^{||} = (y \cdot v_1)v_1 + (y \cdot v_2)v_2
$$
This may look difficult with the square roots that you have, but it turns out that everything factors out nicely.  In particular, we have
$$
(y \cdot v_1)v_1 + (y \cdot v_2)v_2 = \\
\frac 1{14} \Big([3,1,-2] \cdot [0,2,6] \Big)[3,1,-2] +
\frac 1{24}\Big([2,-2,-4]\cdot [0,2,6]\Big)[2,-2,-4]
$$

Comment: I see, but if you go a step further when you have to calculate $$||y-y'|| $$ I still get some odd numbers. Is this normal?

Comment: @John yep, completely normal.